# 5 Beep Code on Gigabye B660M DS3H

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I am trying to build a pc and it will not POST.

I am getting 5 short beep codes which for AMI should be a CPU failure.

The hardware is as follows:

- Gigabyte B660M DS3H DDR4
- Intel i3-12100f
- Corsair Vengeance CMK16GX4M2B3200C16
- Corsair RM750 Power Supply

What I've tried:

- Replacing the motherboard
- Replacing the CPU
- All the different "CPU" sockets on the modular power supply.

It is currently hooked up with just 1 stick of RAM, the CPU, Cooler and the speaker.

All I can think is that the RAM is incompatible at this point? With no memory installed, I get 5 long beeps.

Any troubleshooting tips?

Comment: Standard question, did you take proper anti-static precautions? If not, anything and everything could be broken. Note, touching the radiator occasionally whilst you work on it, is not a proper anti-static precaution.

Comment: Yes I did. I was not so careful the first time (put together quite a few without), new mobo and CPU, I did indeed wear my ESD band.

Comment: Try [this solution](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2299290-pc-beeps-5-short-times-upon-startup).

Comment: Saw that in my googling. I don't believe this board has a bios jumper. The 2 that I can find are a RST and the CMOS. Both don't have any jumpers on them.

Comment: The BIOS jumper is the CMOS jumper. It is marked CLR_CMOS in the manual page 27. You need to short it as per the manual. I assume you have plugged the 2 correct power cables onto the mb and plugged in the cpu fan.

Comment: Yes indeed. I have tried resetting CMOS on both boards just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out and it was an oversight in my build.

The 5 beep codes were to indicate that my CPU did not have onboard graphics (hence the 5 beeps to indicate a CPU error).

I overlooked that a 12100**F** does not include onboard graphics. Threw a graphics card in and everything boots just dandy with no beep codes and full POST.